# unable to create env with yml using anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, yaml, macos-mojave

I’m trying to create a python environment in anaconda.  I’m using a yml file.  I’ve used this same yml file recently to create an environment on another computer.  I used the same command and it worked fine.  Both laptops were macbook pros.  The previous one was running high sierra.  The current mac is running mojave.  Does anyone see what the issue might be?  If I use the exact same file path with vi I can see the contents of the file.  So the file path seems correct.

Code:

```
conda env create -f=/Users/user1/Desktop/stuff⁩/py36_cust1.yml
```

Error:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

EnvironmentFileNotFound: '/Users/user1/Desktop/stuff⁩/py36_cust1.yml' file not found
```

py36_cust1.yml

```
name: py36
channels:
  - anaconda
  - cvxgrp
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - beautifulsoup4
  - patsy
  - sqlite
  - tk
  - asn1crypto
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - cffi
  - clangdev
  - cryptography
  - cryptography-vectors
  - cycler
  - fftw
  - freetype
  - glpk
  - gmp
  - icu
  - idna
  - kiwisolver
  - lapack
  - libiconv
  - libpng
  - libxml2
  - lightgbm
  - llvmdev
  - matplotlib
  - metis
  - mkl_fft
  - mkl_random
  - mlxtend
  - openblas
  - openmp
  - openssl
  - pandas
  - pycparser
  - pyopenssl
  - pyparsing
  - pysocks
  - python
  - pytz
  - selenium
  - tbb
  - urllib3
  - cvxcanon
  - cvxpy
  - ecos
  - multiprocess
  - scs
  - backcall
  - blas
  - cvxopt
  - decorator
  - dill
  - dsdp
  - fastcache
  - gsl
  - intel-openmp
  - ipykernel
  - ipython
  - ipython_genutils
  - jedi
  - jupyter_client
  - jupyter_core
  - libedit
  - libffi
  - libgcc
  - libgfortran
  - libopenblas
  - libsodium
  - mkl
  - ncurses
  - numpy
  - numpy-base
  - parso
  - pexpect
  - pickleshare
  - pip
  - prompt_toolkit
  - ptyprocess
  - pygments
  - python-dateutil
  - pyzmq
  - readline
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - setuptools
  - simplegeneric
  - six
  - suitesparse
  - toolz
  - tornado
  - traitlets
  - wcwidth
  - wheel
  - xz
  - zeromq
  - zlib
  - pip:
    - absl-py
    - astor
    - bleach
    - cython
    - gast
    - grpcio
    - h5py
    - html5lib
    - keras
    - keras-applications
    - keras-preprocessing
    - markdown
    - pillow
    - protobuf
    - pyramid-arima
    - pyyaml
    - sklearn
    - statsmodels
    - tensorboard
    - tensorflow
    - termcolor
    - tqdm
    - werkzeug
    - xlrd
    - libcxx
    - libcxxabi
    - appnope
prefix: /Users/userother/anaconda2/envs/py36
```

Comment: That's a simple File Not Found error.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thank you yes, that seemed to solve the issue.  I moved to the same directory with the yaml file and ran the script and it worked fine, must have been some white space in there somewhere.